# Excel VBA error message - Select method of Range class failed

Tags: excel, vba

When my code executes the following line, I'm getting the "Select method of Range class failed" error message

```
 Range(Workbooks(FileName).Worksheets(ShtName).Cells(1, 1), Workbooks(FileName).Worksheets(ShtName).Cells(LastRow, 30)).Select
```

I'm using variables for the workbook, sheet and last data row.  Why am I getting this error message?

My machine is using Windows 10 and Office 2016.  Thanks for the help....

Comment: You shouldn't `Select` though...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: You also shouldn't use `String` variables here, rather `Workbook` and `Worksheet` variables.

Comment: `Workbooks(FileName).Worksheets(ShtName).Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, 30).Select` but you probably don't need to select.  Also you can't select a Range if the parent sheet isn't active.